# Java adding list of int

Tags: java, list

I have a question about the function I posted bellow.
It does what its supposed to do and even prints out the right value.
However for some reason it also throws an exception. Does anyone know why?

The Function is supposed to add all int values in a list.

```
public int addRecursive(List<Integer> l){
    if(l.size()!=1){
        l.add(l.get(0)+l.get(1));
        l.remove(1);
        l.remove(0);
        addRecursive(l);
    }
return  l.get(0);
}
```

Comment: which `exception`?

Comment: If you pass an emty list you well get out of range exception ;)

Comment: your code works ok in my computer with java 1.7.045

Comment: is the list made up of an odd number of elements?

Comment: You are checking the size equal to `1` and then you are accessing the element in the index of `1`, that might be exception causing point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It seems that the exception went away by restarting eclipse....

Answer (score 0):

you end-up on having an empty list at the end and when:

`l.add(l.get(0)+l.get(1));`

it's runned you will get out well get out of range exception.

so instead of:

```
if(l.size() != 1)
```

you should use:

```
if(l.size() > 0)
```

Comment: this make the function non safe, but OP said: *It does what its supposed to do and even prints out the right value. However for some reason it also throws an exception* that is not problem of `size != 1` because if so, code won't print the right value

Comment: from your judgement I can draw the next conclusion: "maybe the code that throws that exception it's not even this one. I do not see any printlines  here :)

Comment: he might use always an odd number on elements in the list that's why it works

Comment: what I mean is, the code can't throw an exception AND return the correct result...

Comment: @Jordi Castilla i think it work in cases but in others not for example if you pass an empty list or `null` !!

Comment: for this code to work initially need to pass a list which has at least two elements

Comment: as I told, this make function non safe, but does not explain the described behaviour: *it **ALSO** throws an exception*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `if(l.size()!=1)` if `l.size()== 0` you get `IndexOutOfBoundException`

```
public static int addRekursive(List<Integer> l) {

  if (l != null && !l.isEmpty()){
     if (l.size() > 1) {
         l.add(l.get(0) + l.get(1));
         l.remove(1);
         l.remove(0);
         addRekursive(l);
     }
     return l.get(0);
   } else {
     return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: this make the function non safe, but OP said: *It does what its supposed to do and even prints out the right value. However for some reason it also throws an exception* that is not problem of `size != 1` because if so, code won't print the right value

Comment: it would be good if you added a code fragment showing how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the list size is 0, it will raise an IndexOutOfBoundException, you have to modify your code to avoid it (-1 indicates no more elements, return any other value if you want), like this

```
public static int addRekursive(List<Integer> l) {
    if (l.size() >= 1) {
        l.add(l.get(0) + l.get(1));
        l.remove(1);
        l.remove(0);
        addRekursive(l);
    }

    if (l.size() > 0) {
        return l.get(0);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: this make the function non safe, but OP said: *It does what its supposed to do and even prints out the right value. However for some reason it also throws an exception* that is not problem of `size != 1` because if so, code won't print the right value

Comment: The problem raises when he calls to l.get(0) and the list size is 0, even the condition 'size != 1' is incorrect too

Comment: as I told, this make function non safe, but does not explain the described behaviour

Answer (score 0):

i tried this.Its working perfectly.(java version `1.8.0_60`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l.add(12);
        l.add(13);
        l.add(14);
        l.add(15);
        System.out.println(addRekursive(l));

    }

    public static int addRekursive(List<Integer> l) {
        if (l.size() != 1) {
            l.add(l.get(0) + l.get(1));
            l.remove(1);
            l.remove(0);
            addRekursive(l);
        }
        return l.get(0);
    }
```

Output

```
54
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.... i finally got it to work..just by restarting eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

May be because of the if condition. If the list l is empty then the size will be zero and the statements in the if-scope will be executed. Also if the list is null then doing l.getSize() will throw a null pointer exception. So try using the code below and see if the exception is still thrown.

```
public int addRekursive(List<Integer> l){
     if(l != null && l.size() > 1){
          l.add(l.get(0)+l.get(1));
          l.remove(1);
          l.remove(0);
          addRekursive(l);
     }

     if(l != null){
          return  l.get(0);
     }

     return null;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any exception you should test if the list is not empty i used `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils`

And add a return statment befor the call of the same fuction `return addRekursive(l);`

```
public int addRekursive(List<Integer> l) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(l)) {
        if (l.size() > 1) {
            l.add(l.get(0) + l.get(1));
            l.remove(1);
            l.remove(0);
            return addRekursive(l);
        } else {
            return l.get(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And if you pass an empty list you well get `0` as result.

Comment: @Jordi Castilla What about this one??

Comment: @TorbenVerdorben with this solution even if you pass `null` the exception will not be thrown as well